# having issues plotting/doing analysis as part of a column loop in R

Tags: r, loops, plot

I am trying to build a loop where I do non-linear regression of several variables, create and save graphs as a pdf. here is a fraction of the code:

```
    library(propagate)
    library(nlstools) 
    nls_fit_best<-nls(reformulate("a*IDV^b", i),
                  start = list(a = 1, b = 1),
                  control = list(minFactor=0, maxiter=nls_iterations),
                  data=df)

#calculcates the values for the confidence intervals
preds <- data.frame(IDV = seq(min(IDV), max(IDV), length=30))
y.conf <- predictNLS(nls_fit_best, newdata=preds, interval="confidence", alpha=0.05, nsim=10000)$summary

best_fit_coeffs<-as.data.frame(round(coeffs(nls_fit_best), digits=3))
residual_plots<-nlsResiduals(nls_fit_best)

par(mfrow = c(3,3), mar=c(5.1,4.1,2,1.1), oma=c(0,0,0,0))

layout(matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4),nrow=3, byrow = TRUE))

#plots the values into a graph with a bit of wiggle room
plot(i~IDV,
     data=cor_data_centered,
     ylim=c(0,max(i)+0.2,xlim=c(0,max(IDV)+0.2))
#plots best fit line
lines(IDV,predict(nls_fit_best),lty=2,col="black",lwd=3)


#plots 95% confidence interval and info
matlines(preds, y.conf[,c("Sim.2.5%", "Sim.97.5%")], col="black", lty="dashed")
mtext(paste("power function coeffs",best_fit_coeffs,sep=" "), side=3)

plot(residual_plots, which=2)
plot(residual_plots, which=4)
plot(residual_plots, which=6)
}
```

where IDV is my idenpendent variable (i.e, X) - which has 13 measurements. There are 14 variables in the df, with 13 measurments, lets say we have this, to make it easy.

```
IDV=1:13
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1, ncol = 14, nrow = 13))
```

When I run the code i get the following error message

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~i + IDV, data = df) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'IDV')
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

it seems to me that the code is trying to correlate the actualy column names of the data frame with the IDV instead of doing the correlations of each of the variables of the df with IDV. I suppose that the error lies in the initial loop but I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: The code is saying that  `i` is the name of the dependent variable but `i` is the name of variable that contains the name, not the name itself.  Use reformulate to construct the formula `reformulate("a*IDV^b", i)`.  Also `IDV <- seq(1:13)` should be `IDV <- 1:13` .  The model shown does not fit that artificial data well and you likely won't get convergence but I am assuming this is just an example that you have other actual data or different model.  Also the loop keeps overwriting fit on each iteration.  Set `fit <- list()` before the loop and then at each iteration set `fit[[i]] <- ...`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, to make it clear, yes, the data is just random for the example. I have pasted my whole code adding the `reformulate` bit which seemed to fix the NLS part, but I have two more errors when I get to the `plot(i~IDV,` part where it again fails to make the plots and also for the   `ylim=c(0,max(i)+0.2` where it says `Error in max(i) + 0.2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`. Any suggestions?

Comment: That is jjust the same problem as you had before but with plot.  A variable holding a column name and the column name itself are being confused.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to fix it then? I am pretty new to R so I do not know how to make the variable hold the column values instead of the column names

Comment: Use reformulate to create the formula.

Comment: I tried `reformulate("i~IDV",i)` but it did not work, any suggestions?

Comment: `reformulate("IDV", i)`  Please read the help file `?reformulate` and look at the examples on that page.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has a similar problem to mine, I managed to solve the issue with using the minimum of each variable to set the boundaries, using the following code:

```
max_loop=c()
max_loop[i]= max(linear_plots[,i])

min_loop=c()
min_loop[i]= min(linear_plots[,i])


#plots the values into a graph with a bit of wiggle room
plot(reformulate("IDV",i),
     data=cor_data_centered,
     ylim=c(min_loop[i]-wiggle_room_y,max_loop[i]+wiggle_room_y),
     xlim=c(min(IDV)-wiggle_room_x,max(IDV)+wiggle_room_x))
```

With "wiggle room" being whatever value you want to use.